# problem with export animation to fbx

Tags: export

I have an 3d model of a human with an animation on it. I want to export this to FBX to use in PlayCanvas. In PlayCanvas the mesh loads fine but I can't see the animation so I thought maybe there's a problem with the FBX. So i've tried to export to FBX and then Import back into a new blender file. That gave a weird result (see screenshot).
What am I doing wrong?

I started with this;
[image: model with animation to export]

I export using this settings;
[image: settings of FBX export]

This happens when i imported back into blender;
[image]

Comment: Please use latest official version of Blender (2.74) at the very least…

Comment: thx for your response, i've updated to blender 2.74, problem still persists.

Comment: Then I suggest you make a bug report on [our tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug), with example .blend file. :)

Comment: to anyone coming across this question, try to apply all transforms to bones and mesh (Ctrl+A while selecting both objects)

Answer (score 0):

to anyone coming across this question, try to apply all transforms to bones and mesh (Ctrl+A while selecting both objects)